# How to integrate Microsoft Authenticator

Tags: android, google-authenticator, authenticator

How to integrate the Microsoft Authenticator implementation in our app. Can someone share the link for documentation or sample app?

Comment: Don't know why the question is downvoted, please let me know so that I can improve.

Answer (score 0):

Try with Azure Directory and try to expose API of it.
 -The Microsoft and Google Authentication just implement the TOTP mechanism to provide a server-less (read: offline, you only need an accurate timestamp) one time password mechanism. You can use any generic TOTP library to generate a user specific shared secret, possibly encode that one as QR image for ease of configuration and then validate if a provided token matches the shared secret and has been created in the last +-n seconds.

Comment: we want to integrate Microsoft or Google authenticator and implement push notification type authentication but not by sharing the token(access code).

Comment: i am not sure about Authenticator as it doesn't expose api for integration 
 sp try to connect with Microsoft community but with outlook this link will be helpful __https://blog.paranoidpenguin.net/2018/06/office-365-multi-factor-authentication-with-google-authenticator/__

Comment: **https://auth0.com/docs/connections/social/microsoft-account**

Answer (score 0):

You can use a publicly available API (achtung: fremium!):

1. Generate a "secret" code on behalf of your user:

```
AsyncHttpClient client = new DefaultAsyncHttpClient();
client.prepare("POST", "https://microsoft-authenticator.p.rapidapi.com/new_v2/")
    .setHeader("X-RapidAPI-Key", "KEY_GOES_HERE")
    .setHeader("X-RapidAPI-Host", "microsoft-authenticator.p.rapidapi.com")
    .execute()
    .toCompletableFuture()
    .thenAccept(System.out::println)
    .join();

client.close();
```

Server will return you a secret code (e.g. IH225HMVWDS3XJVY). Keep it, because you'll need it at steps 2-3.

2. Generate QR codes for your users:

```
AsyncHttpClient client = new DefaultAsyncHttpClient();
client.prepare("POST", "https://microsoft-authenticator.p.rapidapi.com/enroll/")
    .setHeader("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
    .setHeader("X-RapidAPI-Key", "KEY_GOES_HERE")
    .setHeader("X-RapidAPI-Host", "microsoft-authenticator.p.rapidapi.com")
    .setBody("secret=IH225HMVWDS3XJVY&account=User1&issuer=HomeCorp")
    .execute()
    .toCompletableFuture()
    .thenAccept(System.out::println)
    .join();

client.close();
```

Server will return an url. Pull its PNG data and you get a QR code. Scan it with Microsoft Authenticator app and you'll see TOTPs being generated every 30 seconds.

3. Now validate TOTPs:

```
AsyncHttpClient client = new DefaultAsyncHttpClient();
client.prepare("POST", "https://microsoft-authenticator.p.rapidapi.com/validate/")
    .setHeader("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
    .setHeader("X-RapidAPI-Key", "KEY_GOES_HERE")
    .setHeader("X-RapidAPI-Host", "microsoft-authenticator.p.rapidapi.com")
    .setBody("secret=IH225HMVWDS3XJVY&code=425079")
    .execute()
    .toCompletableFuture()
    .thenAccept(System.out::println)
    .join();

client.close();
```

There are other Java libs available (e.g. using Java libraries java.net.http or OkHttp) here https://rapidapi.com/chdan/api/microsoft-authenticator